# Is this discrete analogue of Fatou's lemma valid

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I was curious if this discrete analog of [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma) is valid:

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{j=1}^\infty \liminf_{k \rightarrow\infty} a_j(k) \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow\infty} \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j(k) ,
> \end{align}
> where $a_j(k)$ is a doubly indexed sequence of real numbers.

Does it hold in the general real case? What if $a_j(k) \geq 0 $, does it hold then? Thanks to all helpers.

Comment: This looks as if it could be useful in other problems, and the accepted answer is a good way to extend integral equations/inequalities to summations.

Comment: Have you tried applying the same method of proof as was used in the standard proof of Fatou?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An infinite sum can be realized as an integral w.r.t counting measure on the integers. So the inequality holds in the non-negative case. Fatou's Lemma requires non-negativity and and the inequality is false without it.

$a_j(k)=-1$ for $j=k$ and $0$ for $j \neq k$ gives a  counter-example.

Comment: Thank you, so if $ a_j(k) \geq 0 $ then it holds?

Comment: @kroner Yes. it is true if $a_j(k) \geq 0$.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

For an elementary proof (without measure) when $a_k(j)$ is nonnegative, note that for all $n \geqslant k$ we have $\inf_{m \geqslant k} a_j(m) \leqslant a_{j}(n)$ and for every positive integer $J$,

$$\sum_{j=1}^J\inf_{m \geqslant k} a_j(m)  \leqslant  \sum_{j=1}^J  a_{j}(n) $$

Thus,

$$\sum_{j=1}^J\inf_{m \geqslant k} a_j(m)  \leqslant  \inf_{n \geqslant k}\sum_{j=1}^J  a_{j}(n) \leqslant \inf_{n \geqslant k}\sum_{j=1}^\infty  a_{j}(n)$$

Taking the limit of both sides as $k \to \infty$  yields

$$\sum_{j=1}^J\liminf_{k \to \infty} a_j(k)   \leqslant \liminf_{k \to \infty }\sum_{j=1}^\infty  a_{j}(k)$$

Finally, taking the limit as $J \to \infty$, we get the result

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\liminf_{k \to \infty} a_j(k)   \leqslant \liminf_{k \to \infty }\sum_{j=1}^\infty  a_{j}(k)$$

Comment: thank you kindly

Comment: @kroner: You're welcome.